# Laplace smoothing parameter choice for Markov chain transitions

Tags: bayesian, markov-process, smoothing, laplace-smoothing

Let $Y_{t}$ be the state of the process at time $t$, ${\bf P}$ be the transition matrix then:

$$ {\bf P}_{ij} = P(Y_{t} = j | Y_{t-1} = i) $$

Since this is a Markov chain, this probability depends only on $Y_{t-1}$, so it can be estimated by the sample proportion. Let $n_{ik}$ be the number of times that the process moved from state $i$ to $k$. Then,

$$ \displaystyle\hat{{\bf P}}_{ij} = \dfrac{ n_{ij} }{ \sum_{k=1}^{m} n_{ik} } $$

where $m$ is the number of possible states ($m=5$ in this case). The denominator, $\sum_{k=1}^{m} n_{ik}$, is the total number of movements out of state $i$. Estimating the entries in this way actually corresponds to the maximum likelihood estimator of the transition matrix, viewing the outcomes as multinomial, conditioned on $Y_{t-1}$.

However if the observed Markov chain was too small a sparse matrix may arise, suggesting some transitions are impossible:

\begin{align}
\widehat{P}_{\text{personal care}}=&\begin{pmatrix}
  0&         0  &       0&    1.00&         0\\
         0&         0 &   0.22&    0.44&   0.33\\
         0&    0.19&    0.57&    0.10&    0.14\\
    0.03&   0.19&    0.09&    0.50&   0.19\\
         0&    0.06&    0.13&   0.56&    0.25\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

This is unlikely and so Laplace smoothing could be used to replace mle:

$$ \hat{{\bf P}}_{ij} = \frac{ n_{ij}+ \alpha}{ \sum_{k=1}^{m} n_{ik} +n_{ij}\alpha}, $$ where $\alpha$ is some smoothing parameter. What criteria can I use to choose $\alpha$?

Comment: I first thought of cross-validation, but I fear that the resulting choice for $\alpha$ would be zero, since $\alpha > 0$ biases the estimate towards the uniform distribution.

Comment: As an alternative to Laplace smoothing, would you consider a Bayesian approach, with a choice of prior that puts some non-null probability on all transitions?

Comment: I am happy to consider this. Why do you think it would improve the estimate in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure that it will improve the estimate (we would need to define in which sense I guess), but it would lead to non-zero transition probabilities unless the data contain enough evidence to shrink some of them to zero. Also, it would allow to differenciate the probabilities for non-observed transitions, which doesn't seem to be the case for the Laplace smoothing.

Comment: I see your train of thought. Do you have a reference for this or an example perhaps?